# Keep the order of parameters fixed in sympy lambdify from free_symbols

Tags: list, set, sympy, lambdify

When asking for a symbol `.free_symbols` I get something in curly braces (which is a `set`).

If I use this set as list of arguments for `lambdify` of sympy  it seems it is converted into a `list`. This is hinted in the [doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) but I suggest a warning to be given here when this conversion is made. A good reason for this is that the ordering of the symbols may be altered in this conversion.

In my case
`_chiSquare.free_symbols` gives `{c_95_0, c_95_1}`
but
`list({'c_95_0', 'c_95_1'})` gives  `['c_95_1', 'c_95_0']`

I like to automate the making of numerical functions using `.free_symbols` but this is hard to work with if order of variable is changed without notice.

My question is how one is supposed to deal with `free_symbols` and `lambdify` in a way that arguments order is kept fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to keep track of the symbols explicitly rather than using `free_symbols`.

If you must work from `free_symbols` then you can sort them to get a consistent ordering:

```
In [3]: sorted((x*y).free_symbols, key=lambda s: s.name)
Out[3]: [x, y]
```

Comment: just to clarify, I am generating my symbols with `sp.symarray` so that the routine can work with functions in `$R^n$` for any $n$, so the explicit tracking is kind of against the purpose. I had missed I can specify the `key` in `sorted` to the `name` attribute. Thanks

Comment: You can get the ordered list of symbols from the symarray with `list(array.flat)`

Comment: just to clarify, the symarray is not available in this application. I have a sympy object as the object returned by a function. The symarray is created in the function, so it is lost outside of it. I only have the sympy expression and need to figure out how to turn it into a function that can be evaluated efficiently numerically for plots, minimization and things like that.